# Was not because of/ but of?

Tags: questions

How do I say this properly, when I want to say that the result was not because of x but of y?

For example: The outcome was not because of x but (of) y?

Do I use of here?

Comment: You could also say - "*The outcome was because of y, not x.*"

Comment: ... but was caused by Y.

Answer (score 1):

'**Because of**' is a [compound preposition {see OALD}](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/because-of) and is never [AFAIK] split.

> A river cuts through rock not because of its power but because of its
>   persistence.

The **whole** preposition may *sometimes* be omitted:

> */??A river cuts through rock not because of its power but its persistence.

but re-ordering may be required:

> A river cuts through rock because of its persistence, not [because of]
>   its power.

Comment: Not because of 'x' but 'y' - Is not wrong, I believe.  Agree with @Edwin

Answer (score 1):

Original:  The outcome was not because of x but (of) y?

I would say parallelism (parallel structures) would require you at least to keep the "of" for clarity.

Either of the below would clearly show the parallel application of "because":

1. ...not because of x but of y
2. ...not because of x but because of y

Without the "of", the application of the parallel application of "because" to y is not clear.